# Split list on given element

Tags: prolog

I have a list `C` and I want to split the list using the element `c` in the list.

The expected results are as example:

```
?- split([a,c,a,a,c,a,a,a],X).
X = [[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]].
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

I can remove the `c` in the list now and here is my codes.

```
split([],[]).
split([H|T],[H|S]) :- H=a,split(T,S).
split([H|T],S) :- H=c,split(T,S).
```

Comment: I'm a new learner, now I can only remove the C in the list but I don't know how to split them. I think it is difficult for me to use this language.

Comment: I want to remove the c in the list first and then split it.

Comment: Maybe, I'm just interesting how to use this language.  But I think it is so tough in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "remove `c`" predicate would look better like this:

```
remove_c([c|T], S) :-
    remove_c(T, S).
remove_c([a|T], [a|S]) :-
    remove_c(T, S).
```

This still only works for lists that have only `c` and `a` in them.

If you want to "split", this means you at least need another argument, to collect the `a`'s between the `c`'s. For example:

```
split_on_c(List, Split) :-
    split_on_c_1(List, Split, []).

split_on_c_1([], [Acc], Acc).
split_on_c_1([c|Rest], [Acc|Split], Acc) :-
    split_on_c_1(Rest, Split, []).
split_on_c_1([a|Rest], Split, Acc) :-
    split_on_c_1(Rest, Split, [a|Acc]).
```

Again, this expects lists of `a` and `c` only. It could also be done in different ways, but this is a start.

Answer (score 1):

While learning a language you need to get accomplished to common abstractions already established (in simpler terms, use libraries). What about

```
split(In, Sep, [Left|Rest]) :-
    append(Left, [Sep|Right], In), !, split(Right, Sep, Rest).
split(In, _Sep, [In]).
```

to be used like

```
?- split([a,c,a,a,c,a,a,a],c,R).
R = [[a], [a, a], [a, a, a]].
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`splitlistIf/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) together with reified term equality 
[`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), like this:

Here is the query the OP gave in the question:

```
?- splitlistIf(=(c),[a,c,a,a,c,a,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]].
```

Note that above code is monotone, so the following query gives reasonable results:

```
?- splitlistIf(=(X),[Y,X,Y,Y,X,Y,Y,Y],Xs), Y = a, X = c.
X  = c,
Y  = a,
Xs = [[a],[a, a],[a, a, a]].
```